# ASA firewalls: how does stateful filtering affect my access lists?

Tags: firewall, cisco-asa, access-control-list

Ok, so assume that I have an ingress access list that looks like this:

```
access-list outside_in extended ip permit any X.Y.Z.1 eq 25
access-group outside_in in interface outside
```

And I want to do egress filtering. I want to allow inside machines to respond on port 80, and I want to allow ports over 1024. Given that the firewall is statefull, do I need to have the rule

```
access-list inside_in extended ip permit X.Y.Z.1 any eq 25
```

in my inside_in ACL, or can I get away with just

```
access-list inside_in extended ip permit any any gt 1024
access-group inside_in in interface inside
```

In other words, if I apply an egress access list, do I have to explicitly allow machines to respond to requests allowed by the ingress access list, or does the statefullness of the firewall handle that for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a TCP connection is established, the traffic flow has been evaluated and allowed, which counts for the lifetime of the flow; the egress rule would not be needed.

Comment: Great, thanks. How does this affect PINGs? I've seen acls that have both "permit icmp any HOST echo" and "permit icmp HOST any echo-reply", if the firewall is statefull then isn't the second rule redundant?

Comment: @Nate It's a little more difficult for it to deal with connections that are inherently stateless, ICMP and UDP.  You'll want the echo-reply rule.  Another IMCP example you'll see sometimes is ICMP unreachable messages.  UDP is usually fine, but you'll see the occasional packet drop when it loses track of a "flow".

Answer (score 0):

To put it very simply: when building rules for TCP connections, you just need to think about the path the first SYN will take. Build the ACLs that would allow those and only those SYNs you consider acceptable, and the firewall will take care of the rest.

I recommend sticking to ingress rules only, unless you have a good justification to do otherwise. This example doesn't look like one.